# PHP/AJAX/Javascript/MySQL Form Submission

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, forms

I'm following a tutorial, this version of the form works, where I use onchange. However, the second version below where I try to use onsubmit doesn't work. Can anyone help please?

```
<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(users.value)">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
    <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
    <option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
    <option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
```

This is the one that doesn't work and I'm not sure why?

```
<form onsubmit="showUser(users.value)">
<select name="users">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
    <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
    <option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
    <option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  >
```

Comment: replace the showUser(users.value) with showUser(this.value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
    <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
    <option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
    <option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
```

For the other one:

```
<form onsubmit="showUser(this.users[this.users.selectedIndex].value); return false;">
<select name="users">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
    <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
    <option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
    <option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Using `return false;` prevents the browser from posting the form to the url and thus reloading the page.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I have the code snippets the wrong way around. The one with onchange works, but the one with onsubmit doesn't. Sorry. I am trying to edit the original post.